# PostgreSQL pq Open not successful: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, go, postgresql-9.1

What is wrong with this code?

http://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq

```
* dbname - The name of the database to connect to
* user - The user to sign in as
* password - The user's password
* host - The host to connect to. Values that start with / are for unix domain sockets. (default is localhost)
* port - The port to bind to. (default is 5432)
* sslmode - Whether or not to use SSL (default is require, this is not the default for libpq)
* fallback_application_name - An application_name to fall back to if one isn't provided.
* connect_timeout - Maximum wait for connection, in seconds. Zero or not specified means wait indefinitely.
```

So I just type the following and expected to see the successful connection with the PostgreSQL connection but seems to not work. Is there anything wrong with the syntax, since the syntax for sql.Open is different than the one that I used for MySQL.

`"dbname=%s user=%s password=%s host=%s port=%s sslmode=%s connect_timeout=%s"`

And the error message from this code is `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

```
package main

import (
  "database/sql"
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "os"

  _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
  db := Get()
  defer db.Close()
  err := db.Ping()
  if err == nil {
    log.Fatalln("db.Ping is successful!")
  } else {
    log.Fatalln(err)
  }
}

func Get() *sql.DB {
  const (
    AWS_DB         = "mydb"
    AWS_USER       = "rootuser"
    AWS_PASS       = "1234"
    AWS_HOST       = "redshift.amazonaws.com"
    AWS_PORT       = "5439"
    AWS_SSL        = "verify-full"
    AWS_TIME       = "2"
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "abcd"
    AWS_SECRET_KEY = "efgh"
  )
  db, err := sql.Open("postgres",
    fmt.Sprintf("dbname=%s user=%s password=%s host=%s port=%s sslmode=%s connect_timeout=%s",
      AWS_DB,
      AWS_USER,
      AWS_PASS,
      AWS_HOST,
      AWS_PORT,
      AWS_SSL,
      AWS_TIME,
    ))
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Error:")
    log.Fatalln(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }
  return db
}
```

Comment: You didn't tell us the error message you are getting.

Comment: There is no error message in this code. It compiles but not connecting to the server.

Comment: So I was guessing if nothing happens with this Open and does not Ping, the syntax might be wrong.

Comment: How do you know it's not connecting to the server?  Did you try running a query against the connection?

Comment: `err := db.Ping()` returns `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` This is the error message. Sorry I was wrong

Comment: have you tried with `sslmode=require`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message tells your host is not trusting the certificate authority (CA) which signed the certificate of your database server.

If you can afford to enable [`InsecureSkipVerify`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) then set `sslmode=require`. This will prevent the client to verify the server's certificate chain and host name (but SSL will still be used).

If this is not an option you need to add the CA to your hosts trusted CAs. This depends on your OS. On Linux you have good chances when you add it to `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`.

Obviously the PostgreSQL driver does not allow to specify a custom `tls.Config` which would make things more flexible. In the [source code](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/conn.go) you can see that it always uses `tls.Config{}`. It does not provide an option to set custom `RootCAs`.

Comment: it's `sslmode=required` not `sslmode=require`

Comment: @holms The documentation says otherwise: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `sslrootcert` parameter. Your code will become

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres",
fmt.Sprintf("dbname=%s user=%s password=%s host=%s port=%s sslmode=%s sslrootcert=%s connect_timeout=%s",
  AWS_DB,
  AWS_USER,
  AWS_PASS,
  AWS_HOST,
  AWS_PORT,
  AWS_SSL,
  AWS_SSL_CERT_PATH,
  AWS_TIME,
))
```

where `AWS_SSL_CERT_PATH="/path/to/the/certificate"`

You can find more information and the link to download the certificate [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL).